# Return a tuple for a forkJoin rxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an array of requests I'd like to execute in parallel with `forkJoin` and then mapped to the result set where the first item is the original object and the second item is the result of the request. For example:

```
const deletionRequests = users.map(user => this.userService.deleteUser(user.id));

forkJoin(...deletionRequests)
    .subscribe(results => console.log(results);
```

Currently, `results` only holds a boolean value but I'd like to instead receive a `[User, Result]` object instead so that I can use this to modify my templates list of users.

Comment: `results` is definitely not a boolean. `forkJoin` always emits an array with that last emission from each source before they complete. It sounds like you want just `[users, ...results]`.

Answer (score 0):

As writ `forkJoin()` should be return an array of boolean values which are in the same order as the array of users.

`results[n]` is the result for `user[n]`

---

That being said, what you want might be closer to

```
const deletionRequests = users.map(user => 
  this.userService.deleteUser(user.id).pipe(
    map(result => ([user, result]))
  )
);
```

This doesn't change `forkJoin` at all, it just alters your array of streams such they they now output a tuple. This might be good if you want to perform extra processing on the users. For example, filtering out bad usernames:

```
const deletionRequests = users
  .filter(user => isFilteredName(user.name))
  .map(user => 
    this.userService.deleteUser(user.id).pipe(
      map(result => ([user, result]))
    )
  );
```

Now users and results don't line up after a `forkJoin`, so the extra processing to map your stream to a tuple is necessary.